# Nginx apply sub_filter directive based on response status code

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have an Nginx server in which I use the [`sub_filter`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter) directive to inject a script in the HTML response by replacing the `</head>` closing tag:

```
sub_filter '</head>' '<script src="some-custom-script.js"></script> </head>';
```

The problem is that I want to conditionally apply the `sub_filter` directive: I want it active only if the response status code is 2xx (e.g. success), and not for error status codes such as 404. The reason is that I do not want the script injected into error page HTMLs.

Is that any way to achieve this "if else" branching in Nginx config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea was using if statement and $status variable but sub_filter can't be used in if only in http, server, location. The same functionality can be implemented with body_filter_by_lua

```
body_filter_by_lua '
    if ngx.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
         ngx.arg[1] = ngx.re.sub(ngx.arg[1], "</head>", "<script src=\"some-custom-script.js\"></script> </head>")
    end
';
```